Cannot pack a newly added layer to the package for QField
I use QGIS (PC) to manage a project and QField (mobile) to sync the data between mobile and PC (using cable export, not QFieldCloud since QFieldCloud only provides 100 MB for free). Everything was fine. The layers are packed into the export folder and transferred to the QField.
However, when I try to create a new layer in QGIS and make a package to export, the newly added layer cannot be added to the export folder. After transferring the folder to Qfield, it showed that the layer was missing. The "Layer action" in the "Configure Current Project" is correctly displayed as "Copy".

The newly added layer's address is not under the import folder like the others.
The correct folder address:

The newly added layer's address:

I would just copy and paste the new layers to the folder on my own. But if I create more than one layer, it would be busy to do so to transfer the data from mobile and PC. Wondering if there is a method to fix it.
